# Unable to Allocate Memory to a Unique Addresses in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, pointers

For class I'm creating a shell in C++. It's been a while since I've worked with C++ so I'm having a bit of trouble. One of the requirements for the project is that I must use the read() system call.

I'm required to keep a command history (similar to bash's if you press the up arrow) that stores the most recent 20 commands. I feel the best way to do this is to use an array of pointers to previous statements. I'm running into a problem where no matter what I do, the string that contains the user input is always stored in the same location in memory. To clarify, this means, if a user inputs 5 statements and then views his/her history, they will see the most recent statement 5 times. My code looks a little something like this (I have to cut some things out because there is a lot of error handling in the middle):

```
char *history[20];
int historyCounter = 0;

while(true){
  char currLine[65];
  int charsRead = read(0,currLine,65);

  char tmp[charsRead];
  strcpy(tmp,currLine); //This is my attempt to ensure the char[] is stored int a 
                        //unique location every time, but this attempt failed.

  history[historycounter] = tmp;
  historycounter++;
}
```

Just to note, in my source, I do handle the case when historycounter > 19. Just not in this snippet.

If any more clarification is required I'd be happy to provide it. This is my first time posting on stack overflow so I apologize in advance if I'm making any sort of rookie mistakes. I also apologize if the solution is painfully obvious. I've been looking at this for a while and it is entirely possible that I'm just not thinking straight.

Comment: Don't use `strcpy` here - `read` does not null-terminate its output and so `charsRead` does not include space for the terminating null character, nor does any terminating null character exist. You should either use memcpy (and keep track of lengths explicitly) or add on a terminating character (and make sure to allocate space for it if you copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `tmp` is most likely to be in the same location, on stack. Its allocated every iteration, and deallocated when the iteration ends.

The line

```
history[historycounter] = tmp;
```

Will lead to undefined behavior when you use it because you'll be using an address of a local variable outside of its scope.

If you want to ensure unique address (and solve the UB problem) - use `new` to allocate the memory, and **don't** use `delete` until you're done. Make sure to keep track of all the allocated pointers and `delete` them when done.

Comment: Wow... This solved my problem. I kind of feel like an idiot now but I'm definitely not afraid to come back with another question. Thanks so much for your quick and helpful response! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Tom any time, for a first timer your question was very clearly formulated and on topic, you'd be surprised how refreshing it is. Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Better yet, don't use `new`.  Use `std::string`, or maybe `std::vector<char>`.  Even better, a memory pool that won't lead to fragmentation.

Comment: @DeadMG don't know what's the point of downvoting the answer, just because you don't like C++. The OP asked a very specific question that I answered. If I answered wrong - do share objections. But you downvoted my answer, basically, because you didn't like the way the OP writes his program. Why is it my fault? And since when new and delete are bad? No-one told me anything about that. A little bit of courtesy and common sense would make you a better person.

Comment: @littleadv: It's been a while since I've seen this question, but let me inform you that manually tracking pointers and `delete`ing them is *not* C++. In fact, it is quite a sin to do so in a program which is supposed to be written in C++. DXM has the correct answer.

Comment: @DeadMG no, the correct answer would be to use smart pointers. However this concept may not be intuitive to everyone. Anyway, its irrelevant to the OP, as I commented on DXM's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing your homework in C++ or in C?

littleadv told you why your program is not behaving correctly.  You never allocated array of strings, instead you only have an array of string pointers but they all end up pointing to the same stack location identified by *tmp*.

However, instead of doing your own pointer manipulation, unlike C, C++ does offer you several higher-level options.  For example, you could declare your array as

```
std::vector< std::string >      listOfCommands;
```

This will take care of all memory management for you. Also instead of using straight globals, consider consider creating a class that would encapsulate the storage and retrieval of your last N commands.  Provide minimal set of public functions for accessing that list (for example arrays and std::vectors allow you to modify any element, but in your application, you only want to write to the end, so your should only have one writer function that only writes to the end). Your *listOfCommands* would then become a private data and the rest of your program wouldn't even need to know how those commands are stored in memory.

This is what programming in C++ (and any other OO) language is about.  Instead of globals, create self-contained building blocks (i.e. classes) which hide most of the complexity, then create larger blocks which rely upon the simpler ones. Keep doing that until your whole application is done.

Comment: Why is this guy the only one who advocated a proper solution? WinRAR.

Comment: @DeadMG because sometimes you're supposed to do what you're told even if some smart asses on SO think its "bad". This answer doesn't answer the question. It gives another way to do things (that you consider "proper", although I have no idea since when using dynamic allocations became unproper), but that is not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a 2-d array and skip all this stuff about trying to ensure unique address and tmp buffer.

```
const size_t MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 65;
typedef char HISTORY_LINE[MAX_LINE_LENGTH+1]; //+1 for null terminator
const size_t MAX_HISTORY_LENGTH = 20;
HISTORY_LINE history[MAX_HISTORY_LENGTH];
int historyCounter = 0;

while(true){
  char* currLine = history[historycounter];

  currLine[0] = '\0';
  int charsRead = read(0,currLine,MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
  if(charsRead > 0)
      currLine[charsRead] = '\0'; // ensure string is null terminated

  historycounter++;
}
```

I skipped all the same error checking as you did, but added a line to ensure that the strings are always null terminated.

Comment: If there's a fixed limit to the number and size of each string, this is much better than using dynamic memory management, since it won't cause memory fragmentation (important for a long-running process such as a shell).

Comment: @DeadMG: Why?  The constants are well-named, and using constants is much better than the magic numbers scattered through the original code.  If you're objecting to the line length restriction, take that up with the OP.

Comment: OTOH, @selbie there's no reason to have a `currLine` array separate from the history.  Just do `char* currLine = history[historyCounter];`.  And make `historyCounter` wrap around and reuse entries, instead of running off the end of the array.

Comment: sure... but I assume he wants to operate on the string just read in before adding it to the history. That's the part of the code not seen... let me see what I can do...

Comment: @DeadMG - I'm just offering a simple solution with the direct intention of not allocating memory - since that is essentially what the OP had originally. In other words, I'm just "cleaning up his code" instead of trying to come up with the ideal solution.

Comment: @selbie: You should never, ever present answers with such code in it. If the OP had such code originally, that's an *even better reason* to not give it in the answer, because he probably doesn't understand how wrong it is.

Comment: @DeadMG - what do you not like about the code?  The read call not actually reading a full line? Something else? If your complaint is that you don't like an array of arrays, then I really don't get it.